# How do I load a file from Chrome extensions for my website

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Bellow is my `manifest.josn`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "speed booster",
  "description": "This extension will Boost Your page speed",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "ajax-loader.gif",
   "default_popup": "style.css"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

After packing my extension `gif, css` file is packed and installed in Chrome

now **How do I use style.css file for my website hosted website** like `CDN` hosted locally?

My chrome extension name is `ex` so i used this on html

```
<link href="chrome-extension://ex/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list any resources that should be accessible in a webpage as `web_accessible_resources` in your extension manifest. See [docs for Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Once you've done that, as the docs explain, your resource should be available using chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]. For example:

```
<link href="chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
```

You can generate this full URL in your extension using [chrome.extension.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL). For example:

```
console.log(chrome.extension.getURL('bootstrap.css'))
```